# Regular expression dot(.) problem

Tags: regex

If you have a string like:

```
"hello my name is joe bloggs! I like stuff"
```

How do you match just `"hello my name is joe bloggs"`? I started off with:

```
(.+)(!)(.+)
```

and at point `!`, I want it to stop.

Please can you answer with the `.` function?

Thanks

Comment: In what language? Can you post your code?

Comment: `(.+(?=\!))` is a start, but too short for an answer :P

Answer (score 3):

You need a question mark:

```
(.+?)(!)(.+)
```

Comment: This works because the question mark makes the `+` non-greedy, so that the first `(.+)` doesn't try to match the whole string before backtracking. For the particular example in the question, the question mark isn't actually necessary, because there's only one question mark - but the nongreedy `+` will be more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

```
([^!]*)(!)(.*)
```

There could be a little difference in that `.` "normally" doesn't "capture" new line, while `[^!]` will, but unless you'll have newlines in your text, you won't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a problem with the `.`; you just have three capture groups: the first `(.+)`, the `(!)`, and the second `(.+)`. If you just want to match a line that ends with a `!`, consider

```
(.+)!
```

but if you want to clearly identify each part of the line,

```
^(.+)!.+$
```

Again, the problem is not with the `.`, but you should have just one group surrounded by parenthesis if you want one capture.